# Solving a differential equation I'm stuck at

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem I'm trying to solve is: $yy''+(y')^2=yy'e^x$

I did $p=y'$ and got: $ypp'+p^2=ype^x$ but I'm not sure what to do after that.

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I just noticed that I don't know how to do second order nonlinear differential equations. My teacher hasn't taught that topic just yet, but it's still in my exam idk why. Can anyone please tell me how to solve it? Hints have been fun to try to solve it but I still have no idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: note that $(yy')' = yy''+(y')^2$, so you can set $yy' = u$ and solve by separating variables.

Answer (score 1):

$$yy''+(y')^2=yy'e^x$$
The LHS is the derivative of $y'y$:
$$\dfrac {dy'y}{y'y}=e^xdx$$
Integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$
\frac{y''}{y'}+\frac{y'}{y} = e^x
$$

or

$$
(\ln(y' y))' = e^x
$$